# Ajax modal pop up not showing for the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Client side:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDynamic" runat="server" Style="display: none">
        <div class="loginwrapper">
            <div class="lgp">
                <h2>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDynamicInfo"></asp:Label></h2>
                <p>
                    <input type="button" id="btnOk" runat="server" value="Ok" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Server side: aspx page

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        lblDynamicInfo.Text = "Fee note has been saved sucessfully. ";
        mdldynamic.Show();
}
```

Comment: What's mdldynamic? It's not defined anywhere?? If you want to change the style of the panel "pnlDynamic" in the code-behind, do this: pnlDynamic.Style.Add("display", "inline");

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender2" runat="server" DisplayModalPopupID="mdldynamic"
            TargetControlID="btnTemp">
           </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdldynamic" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlDynamic"
            TargetControlID="btnTemp" CancelControlID="btnOk" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>    pop id is fired from server side . it is not showing for the first time after that it works fine